# Python Script Returns Garbled Japanese Text To Javascript Via AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, iis, cjk

On an IIS server running Python3 via FastCGI, I am trying to get an HTML file to call a python script, which returns a JSON file containing Japanese text. The Japanese text is getting garbled into mojibake on return. Using Chrome's Network tab to look at the response from the test.py file, I get the following:

```
{ "text": "�e�X�g"}
```

The python script is as follows in a file called test.py:

```
print("Content-type: application/json;\n")
print('{ "text": "テスト"}')
```

The calling HTML snippet is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var httpRequest;
        function makeRequest(){
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (!httpRequest){
                alert('Error: Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
                return false;
            }
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
            httpRequest.open('GET', 'test.py');
            httpRequest.send();
        }
        function displayContents(){
            var text = '';
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE ){
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                    var test = JSON.parse( httpRequest.responseText.trim() );
                    document.getElementById( "mydiv" ).innerHTML = test.text;  
                } else {
                    alert('There was a problem with the request. This can happen if there is no exchange rate data file named exchangerates.json');
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<title>Test Japanese</title>
</head>
<body id="thebody" onload="makeRequest();">
 <div id="mydiv" name="mydiv">testing Japanese...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a bunch of things to try to fix the problem, to no avail. The bizarre thing is that if I try to generate JSON like this from a script, it garbles, but if I write the JSON out to a file and simply have the HTML file retrieve the JSON file, it works fine. I would appreciate any help at this point. I'm running out of hair to pull out.

Comment: I don't think this is caused by IIS, IIS only serves as a container for hosting applications. This should be a coding problem. You can use [json to encode text in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and decode it in html. Whether it is python or html, the general text content must be English, which will not have encoding issues, and other texts need to consider this issue.

Comment: Returning the string was a problem, but if I have the same data in a dictionary object and use JSONEncode.encoder() or json.dumps to serialize the object to a string, THAT string doesn't garble. I hoped I could do a json.loads and then json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False), but that was the same result as sending the string alone. Something about the object to string conversion preserves the Japanese when it is passed back to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many method but only one is useful, that is Json.

Python code:

```
import json
print("Content-type: application/json;")
print()
print(json.dumps({ "text": "テスト"}))
```

When I access the py file directly, It shows this:

[image]

Then I use ajax(the code is same as yours) to call it.
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I mentioned in my reply to you. I did the same thing with with dumps and JSONEncoder.encoder, but I had to use it on the python dict object and not the string. I was curious why I can't just json.loads the string and then json.dumps the string, but it doesn't allow.

Comment: I am not an expert in python, but I think it is meaningless to encode and decode Japanese objects in python. If you encode and then decode, the ajax call is still the Japanese text itself, and there will be garbled characters in the data transmission. But first encoding in python into a format that can be called by ajax, and then decoding into Japanese in html, there will be no such problem.